# ScrollTop to element - 20px

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I'm trying to make a scrollTop to my div element, but not exactly where it is. I want
to go 20px before my div element. I think i can explain better showing my code for you:

HTML:

```
<div id="arrow-down">Click here and go to content!</div>

<div id="content">The content is here!</div>
```

JQuery:
I already have a code that is working fine, but i want to make it diference.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#arrow-down').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
               scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

This code takes me to the div#content, but i want to go 20px from the top of this!

Something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#arrow-down').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
               scrollTop: $("#content" - 20px).offset().top
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

Well, i dont know if its look confused... I hope u guys can help me!

Comment: So subtract the 20 ... `.top - 20`

Comment: you dont want the selector to decrease, you want the offset().top of the element matching to the selector to decrease

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top - 20
}, 800);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#arrow-down').click(function() {
         $('body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top-20
    }, 800);
  }); 
});
```

try this